# Not launching Ipython in my browser on windows 8

Tags: windows, installation, ipython, python-3.4, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to install ipython following official webpage `https://ipython.org/install.html`. I run 
ipython notebook. This is information about my system:

```
Python 3.4.1
ipython 5.1.0

pip3 list
 alabaster (0.7.9), Babel (2.3.4), backports-abc (0.4), colorama (0.3.7), decorator (4.0.10), docutils (0.12), entrypoints (0.2.2),html5lib (1.0b8)
    imagesize (0.7.1), ipykernel (4.5.0),ipyparallel (5.2.0),ipython (5.1.0)
    ipython-genutils (0.1.0),ipywidgets (5.2.2),Jinja2 (2.8), jsonschema (2.5.1)
    jupyter (1.0.0),jupyter-client (4.4.0),jupyter-console (5.0.0),jupyter-core (4.2.0),MarkupSafe (0.23), mistune (0.7.3), nbconvert (4.2.0), nbformat (4.1.0)
    nose (1.3.7),notebook (4.2.3), numpy (1.11.1), pandas (0.18.1)
    pickleshare (0.7.4),pip (8.1.2),prompt-toolkit (1.0.7), Pygments (2.1.3)
    python-dateutil (2.5.3), PyTrie (0.2),PyTrie3 (0.2), pytz (2016.6.1)
    pyzmq (16.0.0),qtconsole (4.2.1),requests (2.11.1), setuptools (28.5.0)
    simplegeneric (0.8.1), six (1.10.0), snowballstemmer (1.2.1)
    Sphinx (1.4.8), testpath (0.3),tornado (4.4.2), traitlets (4.3.1)
    wcwidth (0.1.7),wheel (0.29.0),widgetsnbextension (1.2.6), win-unicode-console (0.5)
```

and I got these errors, I don't know how can handle this error.

```
         jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tornado import gen
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1243, in <module>
    import tornado.platform.asyncio
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 33, in <module>
    import asyncio # type: ignore
  File "c:\python34\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .windows_events import *
  File "c:\python34\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 114, in <module>
    class _WindowsSelectorEventLoop(selector_events.BaseSelectorEventLoop):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BaseSelectorEventLoop'
```

Comment: That's strange, it looks like your installation of Python might be broken. Can you see if `c:\python34\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py` contains `class BaseSelectorEventLoop`?

Comment: @Thomas K It-s really strange this file is zero byte.

Comment: I have updated this file as it was zero byte and now it's working, thx for your comment...

Comment: There is a big problem, after launching it, notebook jupyter is disable and I can't create any notebook!

Comment: What does it look like when you try to create a notebook? Can you show a screenshot? Make sure that you're launching it in a directory where your user account has permission to create files.

Comment: @Thomas K  sorry for answering late, the problem was with python installation in windows, I had to uninstall everything and install anaconda for windows, I have found good explanation in here https://youtu.be/YJC6ldI3hWk?list=PL-osiE80TeTt66h8cVpmbayBKlMTuS55y